# IntelliJ forcing full bracket usage

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style, autoformatting

So i'm using IntelliJ, and whenever I have a single line statement within brackets it makes it one line:

```
public AddChatTrigger(TutorialPlugin plugin) { this.plugin = plugin; }
```

How do I tell IntelliJ to format like so:

```
public AddChatTrigger(TutorialPlugin plugin) { 
    this.plugin = plugin; 
}
```

I tried playing with the code style settigns, but I couldn't seem to find the right one.

Comment: Are you sure the code isn't just collapsed, or "folded" ? Is there a plus mark (`+`) beside it? Does `control - shift - numpad+` unfold them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like code folding. It can be disabled in File | Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding | One-line methods.

Comment: I'll check this when I get home, and you can have a check and a +1 if it's correct. I just started using IntelliJ over eclipse, so I'm still getting used to it.